# toggleClass delay each rows with different times

Tags: javascript, java, php, ajax

I have price table:

```
<div id="one" class="">1.12</div><br>
<div id="two" class="">2.12</div><br>
<div id="tree class="">3.12</div><br>
<div id="for" class="">4.12</div><br>
<div id="five" class="">5.12</div><br>
```

And my ajax codes are below:

```
      <script type="text/JavaScript"> 

    $(document).ready(function() {  

    setInterval(function(){
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: "datas.php",
              dataType: "json",
              contentType: "application/json",
              cache: false,
              success: function(data) {

                <?

             $info = new MYBASE($DB_con);
             $result = $info->getPrices();

             $rnd = rand(10,1200);
             $rnd2 = rand(600,1200);

            foreach($result as $row ) {
            $number = $row['number']; // one, two , tree , for, five
            $newprice = $row['newprice'];
    ?>


             $('#<? echo "$number";?>').html(<? echo $newprice; ?>);
            $('#<? echo "$number";?>').toggleClass('red',<? echo $rnd; ?>).delay(<? echo $rnd2; ?>);

    <?

}
?>

          })            
      },2000);
    });
    </script>
```

I want to add delay time for change each class. Now, all divs refreshing red class 2 seconds after. But I want each row change each delay time after.

How can I do this? I want them to flash, not 2 second after change all of them red class.

Comment: You want to add class "red" to all the div at different time interval right ? i see the issue is you are adding class red in for loop of the first ajax call response, which means all the div are updating at same time. You need to add a delay before adding the class red to the div. Also can you please elobrate what is the need of setinterval here ? Are you calling this AJAX call on every 2 seconds ?

Comment: yes my ajax refreshing table 2 seconds but, i want to change price classes example : each 0.10 seconds with random delay.  and will be change each div class each random delay times.

Comment: The problem is for every 2 seconds you are refreshing the whole table. so within that 2 seconds gap you want all the div to get updated in different time interval which makes it really hard. You have only 5 div ? or the number of div  will get increased ? Because for this 5 div itself you need to divide the interval like for each 0.40 seconds it will update 1 div so at the end of 2 second it will update all the 5 div, Let me know you always have 5 div or the count get increased

Comment: @Ashok i have about 10 div but problem is don't work delays. just showing all divs together red class 2 seconds after.

Comment: All div got the class added at same time because the delay time you have gave is very less then a second which is very hard to notice. What you can do is, add a debugger in the code after the link where you add class "red", now the execution get passed at that mark, there you can notice clearing the class getting added in different interval but since those delay are less then a second we cannot able to find it.

Comment: @Ashok how can i fix it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191267/discussion-between-ashok-and-swiftdeveloper).